# How or where should I add a required connection string for a feature in Helix?

Tags: configuration, helix

A feature requires adding a new connection string. Which should be the way to do this in Helix?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You would need to use an XmlTransform to do this. If you look at the Habitat demo site you can see examples of how to do this.

### Creating the transform file

You would add your connection string to a `ConnectionStrings.config.transform` file - this can live in your project in the `App_Config` folder.

The file is a standard config transform file. Example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<connectionStrings xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <add name="MyDB" 
        connectionString="value for the deployed Web.config file" 
        xdt:Transform="Insert" />
</connectionStrings>
```

### Merging the transform

If you are using the gulp file from the Habitat example, there is already a task that will apply the transforms in the solution:

```xml
04-Apply-Xml-Transform
```

If you are not using that script, you can do the same thing. It calls MSBuild with an `applytransform.targets` file.

The targets file contains:

```xml
<Project ToolsVersion="14.0" DefaultTargets="ApplyTransform" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <UsingTask TaskName="TransformXml" AssemblyFile="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Web\Microsoft.Web.Publishing.Tasks.dll" />
  <Target Name="ApplyTransform">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Transform Include="$(TransformFile)" />

      <ConfigsToTransform Include="$(FileToTransform)" Condition="Exists(@(Transform))">
        <TransformPath>%(Transform.Identity)</TransformPath>
      </ConfigsToTransform>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Message Text="@(ConfigsToTransform)"></Message>
    <Message Text="@(Transform)"></Message>

    <TransformXml Source="$(WebConfigToTransform)\%(ConfigsToTransform.Identity)"
                  Transform="%(ConfigsToTransform.TransformPath)"
                  Destination="$(WebConfigToTransform)\%(ConfigsToTransform.Identity)"
                  Condition="Exists(@(Transform))"/>
  </Target>
</Project>
```

So you can use the MSBuild command line to use that:

```xml
msbuild applytransforms.xml /t:ApplyTransforms
```

More information about how to set this up is here:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465326(v=vs.110).aspx
- http://helix.sitecore.net/principles/configuration/managing-config-files.html#other-config-files

Comment: Beat me to it! ;)

Comment: Note that for connection strings the <configuration> node must be removed. Thanks :)

Comment: Yes - that is because the `ConnectionStrings.config` lives outside the main `web.config`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: So does this Transform just copy the edit in `ConnectionStrings.config.transform` into the `ConnectionStrings.config`? Why not just directly edit the ConnectionStrings.config in that case? Or better yet don't edit it and just deploy `ConnectionStrings.config.transform` as is to the server, since Sitecore would pick up the config file and include it in its aggregate config (e.g. ShowConfig) I just don't get this answer... why a "merge" step?

Comment: This would be for cases where you need to add new connection strings that were not added on install. E.g for a new publishing target database etc... Also, the connection strings config file is not part of the Sitecore patching include system. It is outside of the `<sitecore />` nodes, so you have to deal with it differently.

Comment: @RichardSeal thanks, so is the end result that the Sitecore site's \Website\App_Config folder's `ConnectionStrings.config` would contain the added connection string?